# Unable to implement the react-native-elements Forms?

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I am trying to create a Form which can take user Name and email address with the help of react-native-elements but it is giving error inside render function(Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports).

I have tried to put the FormLabel, FormIput, and FormValidationMessage inside a View and Container in render function but it is giving me an error which I am unable to figure out.

```
import React from 'react';  
import { View, StyleSheet} from "react-native";  
import { FormLabel, FormInput, FormValidationMessage } from 'react-native-elements'  

export default class UserDetailsInput extends React.Component {  

    render() {
        return (
        <View>
            <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
            <FormInput/>
            <FormValidationMessage>Error message</FormValidationMessage>
        </View>
    );
}};
```

package.json

```
{  
    "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",  
    "scripts": {  
        "start": "expo start",  
        "android": "expo start --android",  
        "ios": "expo start --ios",  
        "eject": "expo eject"  
    },  
    "dependencies": {  
        "expo": "^32.0.0",  
        "native-base": "^2.12.1",  
        "react": "16.5.0",  
        "react-dom": "^16.8.6",  
        "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",  
        "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",  
        "react-native-otp-inputs": "^3.0.2"  
    },  
    "devDependencies": {  
        "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"  
    },  
    "private": true  
}
```

I require the react-native-elements to be shown on the UI similar as shown on the docs site.
[image: UI required similar to this one]
<sub>(source: [github.io](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/img/forms_fields.png))</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These components have been renamed or removed in React Native Elements 1.0, your imports therefore yield `undefined`. Please see the corresponding [release notes](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/blog/2019/01/27/1.0-release.html#form).